# more elegant design about enum

Tags: c#, enums

I'm on learning for C#.

I heared C# is one of the most constructible language. so would you guys make my code more elegant and efficient?

```
public class ISO639
{
    public enum ISO639Code
    {
        Afrikaans,                      //af
        Albanian,                       //sq
        Amharic,                        //am

        ...

        Yiddish,                        //yi
        Unknown                         
    }


    public static string GetISO639CodeString(ISO639.ISO639Code l)
    {
        switch (l)
        {
            case ISO639Code.English: return "en";
            case ISO639Code.Japanese: return "ja";

            ...

            case ISO639Code.Hebrew: return "he";
            default: return "";
        }


    public static ISO639.ISO639Code GetISO39CodeValue(string s)
    {

        switch (s)
        {
            case "ko" : return ISO639Code.Korean;
            case "en" : return ISO639Code.English;

            ...

            case "hu" : return ISO639Code.Hungarian;
            default: return ISO639Code.Unknown;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a my class ISO639. This class provides enum for ISO639 code, but I need a type conversion on from ISO639 enum to plain string. (ex. ISO639.ISO639Code.Italian => "it"). I also need a type conversion from plain string to ISO639 enum. (ex. "it" => ISO639.ISO639Code.Italian).

Is there a more efficient coding style for that?

Comment: Most flexible approach that I know for enumeration like functionality are enumeration classes -> http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/08/12/enumeration-classes/ But I doubt you need that. Adding just fyi.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add *standard* [System.ComponentModel.Description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) attribute to each enum entry and then read it.

```cs
public enum ISO639Code       
{ 
  [Description("af")]
  Afrikaans
}

public static class EnumExtensions
{
    // Extension method to read Description value
    public static string GetDescription(this Enum currentEnum)
    {
         var fi = currentEnum.GetType().GetField(currentEnum.ToString()); 
         var da = (DescriptionAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(fi, typeof(DescriptionAttribute)); 
         return da != null ? da.Description : currentEnum.ToString();
     } 
}

// **How-to read it**
ISO639Code isoCode = ISO639Code.Afrikaans;

// this will returns "af"
string isoDescription = isoCode.GetDescription();
```

**EDIT:**

```
    string searchFor = "af"; 
    ISO639Code foundEntry;

    // Loop through all entries descriptions       
    var allEntries = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ISO639Code));
    foreach (var entry in allEntries)
    {
        // If you will extract this as separate method and use it for search not only loop
        // through the all entries - you can put here is yield return description
        var currentEntry = ((ISO639Code)entry);
        string description = currentEntry.GetDescription();
        if (description == searchFor)
        {
            foundEntry = currentEntry;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: good. so how do mapping "af" to Afrikaans directly? should i search all enum memebers through *.GetDescription?

Comment: You want to assign descriptions dynamically or search through the all enum entries by description value? In such case you have to implement method GetByDescription(this Enum currentEnum, string description)

Comment: i want to like...

    ISO639Code l,m;
    k.SetValue("af");
    m=ISO639Code.Afrikaans;

    if(k==m){messagebox.show("equal.");}

this.

Comment: To search by description value you have to implement method GetByDescription(this Enum currentEnum, string description) and loop through all the Enum.GetValues(currentEnum.GetType())

Comment: @mjk6026: I don't got your question, could you please rephrase

Comment: sorry sll. ok now i arrange my question. how can i loop through a enum and get description of theirs?

Comment: sll. thanks very about your efforts. but i'm newbie in C# so i have a some question yet.... 1)how can i modify oneself that extension? (in other words, how modify value of the 'this enum currentEnum' in your GetDescription? i'll try that but it's a value not reference. so i add 'out' and 'ref' keyword to 'this Enum' but it didn't compile. 2)how can i find value of enum by description? (in other words, how get value of that have description "af"?)

Comment: @mjk6026: this is good when you have many questions, this is much better when no questions at all... so post your questions anyway

Comment: Regarding 2) - did you tried solution which I've added to my answer (EDIT part)?

Comment: Add new extension method with second parameter Enum newEnumValue and then you can reassign currentEnum = newEnumValue, smth like this. Really it depends on what you are trying to do, may be simply do it in code rather extension method

Comment: thanks sll. thanks very much. maybe there is no way to set a value to host of extension method. thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Sure. You can use [attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288059%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

```
public enum ISO639Code
{
    [CodeString("af")] Afrikaans,
    [CodeString("sq")] Albanian,    
}
```

Comment: Anton, just a question. How to use this attributes? i.e. from another class. I think this looks pretty clean.

Comment: @Sheldon you need to use reflection and `Attribute.GetCustomAttribute`, usually caching this data somewhere in-memory to avoid calculating it each time

Comment: i have a same question with sheldon.

Comment: Take a look at `DescriptionAttribute`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx

Comment: good. so how do mapping "af" to Afrikaans directly? should i search all enum memebers through *.GetCustomAttribute?

Answer (score 2):

Use dictionary, for example: `new Dictionary<ISO639Code, string>`.

Comment: true, but in many ways the existing code is very readable. It is painfully obvious how it maps. Of course *maintainability* is a sore point, as you could easily swap or typo.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use C# extension methods to enums, they allow you to add whatever logic you want.

For example, see http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/c-enhance-enums-using-extension-methods.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'd simply store the information in a dictionary-like object. This way you can reference the name by key and get the value directly.

Answer (score 0):

You have an enum:

```
 public enum ISO639Code
 {
    Afrikaans = 1,                      
    Albanian  = 2,                       
    Amharic   = 3,
```

etc.

Create a database table:

```
 ISO639Id   int   PK,
 ISO639Code char(2)
```

Where the ISO639Id maps to the value of the enum.

In code you'd want a ISO630 Class containing Id and Code values read from the database.
(You can load this once and then cache it in memory.)

The beauty of this approach, is it can be easily extended so that if in future you wanted to store more pieces of information for each ISO639 code, you could simply add another field.

Answer (score 0):

Look at System.Globailzation namespace. The functionality you require looks to be already implemented there. At worst you can see the architecture and technique applied in the .Net framework to solve a very similar problem.

Comment: thanks for malio. but i want to know about C#, not .net framework namespace.

Comment: But the point is there are normally better ways of representing some structures, but it depends entirely on how they are to be used. For languages, the CultureInfo classes exist.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerations are really good to work in code, as they are really strongly typed and make refactoring easier.
Follow these steps:

1. Use attributes for whatever extra information you want to attach to an enum. Usually this is a simple `Description` attribute. Something like:

   public enum IsoCodes
   {
       [Description("af")]
       Africans = 0,
       [Description("am")]
       Americans = 1
   }

Then write some extension methods to convert strings and integers to and from this enum:

```
public static string GetDescription(this Enum value)
        {
            var entries = value.ToString().Split(FlagEnumSeparatorCharacter);

            var description = new string[entries.Length];

            for (var i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
            {
                var fieldInfo = value.GetType().GetField(entries[i].Trim());
                var attributes = fieldInfo.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false) as DescriptionAttribute[];
                description[i] = (attributes.Length > 0) ? attributes[0].Description : entries[i].Trim();
            }

            return String.Join(", ", description);
        }

public static int GetValue(this Enum value)
    {
        return (int)value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString()).GetRawConstantValue();
    }

    public static T ToEnum<T>(this string value)
    {
        if (typeof(T).BaseType.Name != typeof(Enum).Name)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not an enum");
        }
        return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), value, true);
    }

    public static T ToEnum<T>(this int value)
    {
        if (typeof(T).BaseType.Name != typeof(Enum).Name)
        {
            throw new Exception("Not an enum");
        }
        return (T)Enum.ToObject(typeof(T), value);
    }
```

Now use your enums as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with having `ISO639Code` as class instead of enum:

```
public class ISO639Code
{
    public string Value { get; set ; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

    public ISO639Code()
    {
        this.Value = "";
        this.Code = "";
    }

    public ISO639Code(string value, string code)
        : this()
    {
        this.Value = value;
        this.Code = code;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            if (obj is string)
                return obj.ToString().Equals(this.Value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
            if (obj is ISO639Code)
                return ((ISO639Code)obj).Value.Equals(this.Value, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return this.Value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Value;
    }
}
```

Then have global `List<ISO639Code>` with all possible codes, and to find specific code based on code name or value, just search for this in the List.

Personally, I prefer this over tweaking the enum.

Comment: I believe Code property should be readonly, because it not makes sense to change code whilst entity life cycle (for this particular case)

Comment: Valid argument, this code is given as example - not sure about the full scope here though.